# $E(\overline{x})$ vs $E(x)$?

Tags: self-study, variance, mean

If I have a problem down to

$$k(E(x^2) - E(x)^2) = E(\overline{x}^2) - E(\overline{x})^2$$

...can I say $k = 1$? $X$ has an unbiased mean and a variance.  Each $x$ in $X$ is independent.

Or is it more complex than that?  If it's not clear, $\overline{x}$ signifies the average (or mean or whatever, I always thought they were the same until this homework assignment...)

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure you are not missing any further informations? Firstly, when you say "unbiased mean" it is the estimator of the mean of $X$ i.e $\hat{\bar{X}_{n}}$ which is unbiased, not the mean of $X$.

You should not confuse the mean of your estimator AND the mean of your distribution.
Let's change the notation just to be clear.

Let  $\mu=E(X)$ be the **TRUE mean** of your ditribution and $\hat\mu_{n}$ the **ESTIMATOR of the mean**. Usually $\hat\mu_{n}=\frac{\sum\limits_{k=1}^n x_{k}}{n}$.The estimator is a way to compute the mean and it is also a random variable. So it has also a mean and a variance. In your formula $E(\bar{x})$ corresponds to $E(\hat\mu_{n})$: the mean of the estimator of the mean (it's weird I know).

When you compute the variance of your estimator you have the following property:
$Var(\hat\mu_{n})=\frac{Var(X)}{n}$. Where $n$ is the total number of samples of your distribution of $X$.

So $k=\frac{1}{n}$

Go check http://www.statlect.com/mean_estimation.htm and http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Estimator for more infos.

I hope it's clear. Do not hesitate to ask for more details!